# Convergence of a sequence of Functions .

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Let the function sequence  $\{f_n\}$ be defined by $f_n(x)= x - 2 \exp(-nx) $ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$ . Now let $f :\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ be defined by $f(x)= x-2I\{0\}(x)$ for $x \in [0,\infty]$.Then $f$ is  the limiting function of $\{f_n\}$ on the set $[0,\infty)$ and the sequence $\{f_n\}$ does not converge for $x < 0$ .

My question is :

- Why the function $f(x)=x$ for $x > 0 $ is not the limiting function of $\{f_n\}$ , since the term $2\exp(-nx)$ will approach zero as $n \rightarrow \infty$ for $x >0$ and this term will be undefined when $x=0$ since $0 \times -\infty$ undefined ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that if $x>0$, then $f(x)=x$ so this is the limiting function *on $(0,+\infty)$*. The role of the indicator function of $\{0\}$ is to have a formula with also works for $x=0$.